# "Multiply" 1d numpy array with a smaller one and sum the result

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to `"multiply"` (for lack of better description) a numpy array X of size M with a smaller numpy array Y of size N, for every N elements in X. Then, I want to `sum` the resulting array (almost like a `dotproduct`).

I hope the example makes it more clear:

```
Example
X = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Y = [1,2,3]

Z = mymul(X, Y)
  = [0*1, 1*2, 2*3, 3*1, 4*2, 5*3, 6*1, 7*2, 8*3, 9*1]
  = [  0,   2,   6,   3,   8,  15,   6,  14,  24,   9]

result = sum(Z) = 87
```

X and Y can be of varying lengths and Y is always smaller than X, but not necessarily divisible (e.g. M % N != 0)

I have some solutions but they are quite slow. I'm hoping there is a faster way to do this.

```py
import numpy as np
X = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int)
Y = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=int)

# these work but are slow for large X, Y

# simple for-loop
t = 0
for i in range(len(X)):
  t += X[i] * Y[i % len(Y)]
print(t) #87

# extend Y M/N times so np.dot can be applied
Ytiled = np.tile(Y, int(np.ceil(len(X) / len(Y))))[:len(X)] 
t = np.dot(X, Ytiled)
print(t) #87
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resize `Y` to same length as `X` and then use matrix-multiplication -

```
In [52]: np.dot(X, np.resize(Y,len(X)))
Out[52]: 87
```

Alternative to using `np.resize` would be with tiling. Hence, `np.tile(Y,(m+n-1)//n)[:m]` for `m,n = len(X), len(Y)`, could replace `np.resize(Y,len(X))` for a faster one.

Another without resizing `Y` to achieve memory-efficiency -

```
In [79]: m,n = len(X), len(Y)

In [80]: s = n*(m//n)

In [81]: X2D = X[:s].reshape(-1,n)

In [82]: X2D.dot(Y).sum() + np.dot(X[s:],Y[:m-s])
Out[82]: 87
```

Alternatively, we can use `np.einsum('ij,j->',X2D,Y)` to replace `X2D.dot(Y).sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `convolve` ([documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)):

`np.convolve(X, Y[::-1], 'same')[::len(Y)].sum()`

Remember to reverse the second array.